# Is it acceptable to dynamically update UI in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad

We are creating an iPad app that connects to a web service using the user's id. Depending on their profile, we need to hide certain UI elements (tabs, toolbars).

In the HIG, under Tab Bar, it says "If a tab represents a part of your app that is unavailable in the current context, it’s better to display a disabled tab than to remove the tab altogether."

This will not work for the app for business reasons. Is anyone able to elaborate on whether the quote above is a hard and fast rule or just a guideline?

Comment: "it’s better to" isn't exactly strong wording.

Comment: Isnt the HIG technically under Apple NDA?

Comment: @logixologist, thanks for the heads up; I didn't think posting a quote from it would be an issue, but I will remove it.

Comment: The HIG is not under NDA. It is publically visible at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html.  Googling "ios human interface guidelines" finds that as the first hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a business rule, so be it. Apple's Human Interface Guidelines are just that... guidelines. Not a hard rule, sometimes they don't make sense for your application.

Comment: @Ooklamok And for you to breath easy, I had one app which showed different number of tabs for different logins got approved without any problem.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra This actually does help me "sell" it to my colleagues. Thanks!